# Which Doctors have enjoyed longest and shortest period of their lives?

Tags: doctor-who

As the title says, which incarnations of the Doctor lived longest and shortest? Here, I am not talking about age, but the period. For example, when The Master increased the age of The Doctor by 900 years, that would be counted as 1 year.

Comment: How can you tell? He is a time traveler, he could have gone on solo adventure that lasted 200 years between the episodes. I think the best example is Matt Smith in the Impossible Astronaut where you meet the same incarnation about 300 hundred years apart (I think).

Comment: What do you want to count as canon for the purpose of this question? Only the TV series, or also audios and/or books? A lot of what we "know" about the ages of different incarnations is from sources other than the show, see [The Doctor's Age](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_age) for a good rundown.

Comment: Shortest?  That would be [Richard E Grant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Do-wDPoC6GM), I think. :-)

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Elevent is the longest, followed by One. The shortest is harder to pin down but it's definitely either Eight, Nine, or The War Doctor.

---

As far as I know, the incident you mentioned with Ten being artificially aged 900 years is the only time The Doctor's age has increased in non-real-time (for him). So, the answer to both questions "who lived the longest" and "who aged the most" are otherwise the same.

The longest was Eleven, because of the roughly 900 years he spent on Tenzalore near the end of his life; prior to that, I believe the First Doctor was around 450 years old when he regenerated.

The shortest is a bit hard to pin down because *Doctor Who* was pretty sloppy with their ages and timelines prior to Ten's incarnation. If we just look at the classic show, it's pretty easy. We know that both Six and Seven, spent approximately 50 years as The Doctor before regenerating, which is smaller than any other **classic** regeneration by about 2/3.

**However**, around the time of the Last Great Time War, things go *really* wonky. Eight claimed to be about 1000 years old when he first appeared, and Nine later claimed to be about 1100 years old (indirectly, assuming he was ~200 when he stole the TARDIS). That means he spent around 100 years being both the Eighth Doctor **and** the War Doctor, with no way of knowing where that cut-off is.

Even worse, Ten later claims to be 903, meaning he somehow aged *backwards* between Nine and Ten.

So we really have *no idea* how long Eight, Nine or the War Doctor spent as The Doctor, but there's no way all three of them were The Doctor for more than 50 years. *At least* Eight or War must have been The Doctor for less than 50 years, and I *suspect* Nine is as well, since we watched almost his entire run as The Doctor occur in real-time with Rose.

Comment: The problem with taking Nine's "900 years of phone box travel" to refer to just his time in the TARDIS is that Ten said "I'm 903 years old" in "Voyage of the Damned", which sounds like a straightforward statement of age rather than time spent traveling. And in "The Doctor's Wife" when the Doctor asks the embodied TARDIS her name, she says "700 years, finally he asks". Maybe Nine was just saying it *seemed* like he'd been traveling his whole life, or maybe he really had regularly been traveling in TARDIS-style vehicles (field trips and such) even before he stole the TARDIS.